# Issue with Exporting Cycle into CSV filetype in Zephyr Squad REST API

Tags: python, api, rest, jira-rest-api, jira-zephyr

Followed Official Doc:
 [Zephyr Squad Cloud REST API (formerly Zephyr for Jira)](https://zephyrsquad.docs.apiary.io/#reference/cycle/export-cycle/export-cycle)

Getting ***`Missing parameter: projectId`*** as a response from Zephyr Squad. I am not getting why parameter of `projectId` is missing even though I have been passing this in parameters of `CANONICAL_PATH` and from the Json `cycle`?

```
RELATIVE_PATH = '/public/rest/api/1.0/cycle/{}/export'.format(cycle_id)

CANONICAL_PATH = 'GET&/public/rest/api/1.0/cycle/' + cycle_id + '/export?' + 'projectId=' + str('10000') + '&versionId=' + str('10000') + '&exportType=' + str('CSV')
```

**Actual Result:**

```
<Response [400]>
{
    "clientMessage": "Missing parameter: projectId",
    "errorCode": 151,
    "errorType": "ERROR"
}
```

**Expected Result:**
Response status should be 200 and save the file into CSV format

**Complete Snippet:**

```
import json
import jwt
import time
import hashlib
import requests


def is_json(data):
    try:
        json.loads(data)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

# USER
ACCOUNT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# ACCESS KEY from navigation >> Tests >> API Keys
ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# ACCESS KEY from navigation >> Tests >> API Keys
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# JWT EXPIRE how long token been to be active? 3600 == 1 hour
JWT_EXPIRE = 3600

# BASE URL for Zephyr for Jira Cloud
BASE_URL = 'https://prod-api.zephyr4jiracloud.com/connect'

# RELATIVE PATH for token generation and make request to api
cycle_id = 'ca55798e-e9e8-4ebb-8b43-efac9360e615'

RELATIVE_PATH = '/public/rest/api/1.0/cycle/{}/export'.format(cycle_id)

CANONICAL_PATH = 'GET&/public/rest/api/1.0/cycle/' + cycle_id + '/export?' + 'projectId=' + str('10000') + '&versionId=' + str('10000') + '&exportType=' + str('CSV')


# TOKEN HEADER: to generate jwt token
payload_token = {
            'sub': ACCOUNT_ID,
            'qsh': hashlib.sha256(CANONICAL_PATH.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(),
            'iss': ACCESS_KEY,
            'exp': int(time.time())+JWT_EXPIRE,
            'iat': int(time.time())
        }

# GENERATE TOKEN
token = jwt.encode(payload_token, SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256').strip()

# REQUEST HEADER: to authenticate and authorize api
headers = {
            'Authorization': 'JWT '+token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'zapiAccessKey': ACCESS_KEY
        }

# REQUEST PAYLOAD: to create cycle
cycle = {
            'versionId': 10000,
            'projectId': 10000,
            'exportType': 'CSV',
            'folderId': 'UI'
        }

# MAKE REQUEST:
raw_result = requests.get(BASE_URL + RELATIVE_PATH, headers=headers, json=cycle)
print(raw_result)

# Download the CSV file and save it to disk
with open("Export.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    csvfile.write(raw_result.text)

if is_json(raw_result.text):

    # JSON RESPONSE: convert response to JSON
    json_result = json.loads(raw_result.text)

    # PRINT RESPONSE: pretty print with 4 indent
    print(json.dumps(json_result, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

else:
    print(raw_result.text)
```

Comment: Maybe in your RELATIVE_PATH don't have projectId param